# why I am not able to start the ftp service in /etc/services

Tags: raspberry-pi, services, ftp, systemctl

I want to enable FTP on my Raspberry PI which comes shipped with Debian Linux. I am able to find out the service available in `/etc/services` file.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7l+ #1327 SMP Thu Jul 23 11:04:39 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux

root@raspberrypi:~# cat /etc/services | grep ftp
ftp-data        20/tcp
ftp             21/tcp
tftp            69/udp
sftp            115/tcp
ftps-data       989/tcp                         # FTP over SSL (data)
ftps            990/tcp
venus-se        2431/udp                        # udp sftp side effect
codasrv-se      2433/udp                        # udp sftp side effect
gsiftp          2811/tcp
gsiftp          2811/udp
frox            2121/tcp                        # frox: caching ftp proxy
zope-ftp        8021/tcp                        # zope management by ftp
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

When I attempt to start the service via `systemctl` it gives me the following error.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# systemctl start ftp.service
Failed to start ftp.service: Unit ftp.service not found.
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

I would like to start with the default FTP service shipped with the Linux Distribution, before I try out with the tools like `pure-ftp` or `vsftpd` etc.,

Can you please help me with the gaps on my approach?

Comment: You have to install ftp server. `pure-ftp` or `vsftpd` are the choices to be used. I don't think there is a default FTP service shipped with the distribution. `/etc/services` is just a file that provides services names for ports. It just says that port 21/tcp is reserved for ftp. Look here: https://www.cs.clemson.edu/course/cpsc424/material/TCP%20UDP%20Services/etc-services.pdf

Comment: There is no default ftp service. `/etc/services` is not a list of services you have installed. https://askubuntu.com/a/1012782/158442

Comment: Thank you @nobody. I was under an impression the OS comes with the services on those standard ports and we just need to enable it. Sure, let me try with the FTP Servers and check.

Comment: Thank you @muru for the link to the thread for an explanation. It helps.